# How to setup docker registry in k8s cluster?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-registry

There is no requirement for secure registry. I just need to connect to a registry using http protocol.

The registry must be on a pod and not directly on the VM.

docker has `registry` image that is made just for this purpose but when I'm using it inside a pod, docker fails to communicate with it because it thinks its a secure registry:

```
> docker pull 192.168.64.3:31549/repo630444582240256/image1

Using default tag: latest
Error response from daemon: Get https://192.168.64.3:31549/v2/: http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client
```

---

I came across these solutions but each of them requires installing prerequisits in the VM or doesn't use a pod to setup a registry:

- https://github.com/SeldonIO/k8s-local-docker-registry
- https://github.com/alexellis/k8s-tls-registry
- https://github.com/ContainerSolutions/trow

---

```
> set -x && curl -X GET 192.168.64.3:31549/v2/_catalog

+ curl -X GET 192.168.64.3:31549/v2/_catalog
{"repositories":[]}
```

Comment: set -x && curl -X GET http://192.168.64.3:31549/v2/_catalog
what is the output of this ?

Comment: @AbhishekDK I updated the question with the result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried this on my local machine: https://github.com/SeldonIO/k8s-local-docker-registry and works like a charm. ([I had to make a few changes to the K8s manifests so they support the latest K8s](https://github.com/raravena80/k8s-docker-private-registry))

You can get to the registry using `curl -X GET 192.168.64.3:31549/v2/_catalog` which means there is no redirect to https.

I believe your docker client config doesn't have explicit `Insecure Registry` config for `192.168.x.x`.  You can check with:

```
$ docker info | grep -i -A5 'Insecure Registries'
 Insecure Registries:
  10.96.0.0/12
  127.0.0.0/8
  192.168.64.0/24  <== should have something like this
```

If not you can configure your `192.168.0.0/24` as an [insecure registry](https://docs.docker.com/registry/insecure/) in the `daemon.json` config:

```
{
  "insecure-registries" : ["10.96.0.0/12", "127.0.0.0/8", "192.168.64.0/24" ]
}
```

Comment: for other people that comes here, please specify the changes that you did. I also want to make sure that I have done them correctly and as you did. Anyway, thank you for taking the extra mile for me! It's working :)

Comment: Sure, added a link :-)

Comment: thank you for all the help. if thats ok, I would like to ask for your help in here also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62600611/get-labels-of-remote-docker-image

Answer (score 1):

just came across another path where you can add the insecure registries

```
$ vi /var/lib/boot2docker/profile
```

add the following

> EXTRA_ARGS='
> --label provider=virtualbox
> --insecure-registry 127.0.0.0/8
> --insecure-registry 192.168.99.0/24
> '

restart docker daemon

```
$ /etc/init.d/docker restart
```