# Get labels of remote docker image

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I'm trying to get the labels of an image without pulling it.

For example: in docker-hub, on my username (`stavalfi`), in repo: `projecty`: https://hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/stavalfi/projecty/tags

I want to get all the labels of this image.

Following this guide: https://hackernoon.com/inspecting-docker-images-without-pulling-them-4de53d34a604

and this: https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/#pulling-a-layer

I tried to reach to: `http://$REGISTRY_ADDRESS/v2/$image/blobs/$digest`:

https://hub.docker.com/v2/stavalfi/projecty/blobs/sha256:7701c1411c0e438c5bfb1d7b4c1f337ee75b4a3a1d8492fc3b608cdc2b320a9d

but the result is a 404.

What is the problem?

---

**I can't use `skopeo` because it can't inspect registries with an HTTP connection (insecure).**

Comment: To verify, do you want labels or only the list of tags?

Comment: I need the labels. I gave the tags example to show you what I could achieve using v2 api.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can find the labels in the first layer of the docker manifest:

```
$ repo=stavalfi/k8test-monitoring                                                                                                                                                                                 

$ token=$(curl -s "https://auth.docker.io/token?service=registry.docker.io&scope=repository:${repo}:pull" \
  | jq -r '.token')

$ curl -s -H "Authorization: Bearer $token" "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/${repo}/manifests/latest" \
  | jq ".history[0].v1Compatibility" -r | jq .config.Labels
{
  "latest-hash": "dc971f310bd0b172fd0379cc9a1810f209c9a9604a28da14cef36457",
  "latest-tag": "1.3.4"
}
```

---

Update: the v2 registry API is a bit cleaner, but needs one more curl:

```
$ repo=stavalfi/k8test-monitoring                                                                                                                                                                                 

$ token=$(curl -s "https://auth.docker.io/token?service=registry.docker.io&scope=repository:${repo}:pull" \
        | jq -r '.token')

$ digest=$(curl -s -H "Accept: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json" -H "Authorization: Bearer $token" "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/${repo}/manifests/latest" \
  | jq .config.digest -r)

$ curl -s -L -H "Accept: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json" -H "Authorization: Bearer $token" "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/${repo}/blobs/$digest" \
  | jq .config.Labels
{
  "latest-hash": "dc971f310bd0b172fd0379cc9a1810f209c9a9604a28da14cef36457",
  "latest-tag": "1.3.4"
}
```

---

For a more generic use case, here's a script to pull the config of any public image on docker hub without downloading the full image:

```
#!/bin/sh

repo=${1:-library/ubuntu}
tag=${2:-latest}
token=$(curl -s "https://auth.docker.io/token?service=registry.docker.io&scope=repository:${repo}:pull" \
        | jq -r '.token')
digest=$(curl -H "Accept: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json" \
              -H "Authorization: Bearer $token" \
              -s "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/${repo}/manifests/${tag}" | jq -r .config.digest)
curl -H "Accept: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json" \
     -H "Authorization: Bearer $token" \
     -s -L "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/${repo}/blobs/${digest}" | jq .
```

Just make sure to include the "library" prefix for official images:

```
$ ./get-config-v2.sh library/alpine 3.9
{
  "architecture": "amd64",
  "config": {
    "Hostname": "",
    "Domainname": "",
    "User": "",
    "AttachStdin": false,
    "AttachStdout": false,
    "AttachStderr": false,
    "Tty": false,
    "OpenStdin": false,
    "StdinOnce": false,
    "Env": [
      "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
    ],
    "Cmd": [
      "/bin/sh"
    ],
    "ArgsEscaped": true,
    "Image": "sha256:186eda4636e895d982896312666e472a2d62aab1490608701e1b3438ac6649e7",
    "Volumes": null,
    "WorkingDir": "",
    "Entrypoint": null,
    "OnBuild": null,
    "Labels": null
  },
  ....
```

---

Since this answer was first posted, I've also created [regclient](https://github.com/regclient/regclient/) which includes the command regctl. This handles authentication, allows you to configure a registry without TLS or with a self signed certificate, resolves multi-platform images, and includes support for Go templates to extract the specific fields you want:

```
$ regctl image config regclient/regsync:latest --format '{{ jsonPretty .Config.Labels }}'
{
  "maintainer": "",
  "org.opencontainers.image.authors": "Regclient contributors",
  "org.opencontainers.image.created": "2021-04-02T18:55:09Z",
  "org.opencontainers.image.description": "",
  "org.opencontainers.image.documentation": "https://github.com/regclient/regclient",
  "org.opencontainers.image.licenses": "Apache 2.0",
  "org.opencontainers.image.revision": "5a6a1d95524b9c1c2d38a5af7ab744742f8d55e9",
  "org.opencontainers.image.source": "git://github.com/regclient/regclient.git",
  "org.opencontainers.image.title": "regsync",
  "org.opencontainers.image.url": "https://github.com/regclient/regclient",
  "org.opencontainers.image.vendor": "",
  "org.opencontainers.image.version": "v0.3.0"
}
```

Comment: Thank you! what does `v1Compatibility` means? will it be supported in future docker api releases?

Comment: @StavAlfi There is a v2 API that's preferred, getting that scripted up for you now, will update in a moment.

Comment: excellent! Thank you very much! this is actually the only resource online that actualy has a working example for using these apis. thanks again for your time and +100 <3 for the working example!

Comment: Are there any updates regarding the API now? It seems some new changes broke the shell script.

Comment: @devster it's the same API, but images can be uploaded with different media types, rate limits can affect requests, multi-platform images and build attestations could cause issues. The shell script just takes a very simple happy path and assumes none of those will be an issue. The regctl command, along with tools like crane or skopeo, all handle this much better, with support for more registries and media types, and even let you pick which platform for a multi-platform image.

Answer (score 4):

this worked for me, you can try this

```
curl 'https://registry.hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/< username>/<repo>/tags/'|jq '."results"[]["name"]'
```

regarding blob,  token need to be generated then use this token for blob

```
export TOKEN=\
"$(curl \
--silent \
--header 'GET' \
"https://auth.docker.io/token? 
service=registry.docker.io&scope=repository:<username>/<repo>:pull,push" \
| jq -r '.token' \
)"
```

now get the manifest of the image

```
curl \
--silent \
--request 'GET' \
--header "Authorization: Bearer ${TOKEN}" \
'https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/<username>/<repo>/manifests/<latest>' \
| jq '.'
```

now get the blob for that image

```
curl \
--silent \
--request 'GET' \
--header "Authorization: Bearer ${TOKEN}" \
"https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/<username>/<repo>/manifests/19" \
| jq -r '.fsLayers[].blobSum'
```

the above command gives the list of digests which can be used to fetch the image
set the following variable

```
DIGEST=<SHA:somevalue>  

curl \
--silent \
--location \
--request GET \
--header "Authorization: Bearer ${TOKEN}" \
"https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/<username>/<repo>/blobs/${DIGEST}" > 
"${DIGEST/*:/}.gz"
```

Comment: i already added a working example of getting the tags just like you did in the question. what im looking for is a working exaple of how to get the labels. and I tried to follow a guide to get the token and its still not working. (the guide is in the question also)

Comment: worked for me, when i used this token based approach

Comment: which digit should I take for the last command? the first cell or the last cell?

Comment: and how do I extract the labels from the <digit>.gz file?

Comment: can I get the labels without pulling the image?

Comment: curl --silent --header "Accept: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json" 
--header "Authorization: Bearer ${TOKEN}" 
 "http://registry-1.docker.io/v2/<username>/<repo>/manifests/<latest>" | jq -r '.[0].Config.Labels'

Comment: no labels in the result. try it your self: `curl --header "Accept: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json" --header "Authorization: Bearer ${TOKEN}" "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/stavalfi/k8test-monitoring/manifests/latest"`