# Get container image label without pulling the image from GCR

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, docker-container, google-container-registry

I am trying to create a dataset for at least 250 container images built by docker and pushed to a single GCP project on Google Container Repository (GCR). The GCR is highly active, thus it changes the version quite frequently, thus the automation.

All of these images add a certain label at the time of push from the CI system. I want to add those labels in the dataset. I tried accessing the label and its value after pulling the image, however, pulling 250+ images and then inspecting them is taking too much resources on this automation and may not even be possible.

So in short, I just want to know if there's any `gcloud` API (REST or CLI) which can fetch the label metadata without pulling the image first?

I tried looking in the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/managing), but couldn't find anything. I tried the following command which only gives the SHA256 digest and the repository details, but not labels

```bash
gcloud container images describe gcr.io/[PROJECT-ID]/[IMAGE]
```

```bash
# Output

image_summary:
  digest: sha256:[SHA_DIGEST_HERE]
  fully_qualified_digest: gcr.io/[PROJECT-ID]/[IMAGE]@sha256:[SHA_DIGEST_HERE]
  registry: gcr.io
  repository: [PROJECT-ID]/[IMAGE]
```

**Update:**
I tried the curl command with the access token which gave me different layers instead

```bash
$> curl https://gcr.io:443/v2/[PROJECT-ID]/[IMAGE]/manifests/latest -H "Authorization: Bearer {token}"
```

```json
// output

{
   "schemaVersion": 2,
   "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json",
   "config": {
      "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.container.image.v1+json",
      "size": [size],
      "digest": "sha256:[SHA_256_DIGEST]"
   },
   "layers": [
      // different layers here
      ]
}
```

Not sure how can I actually extract the manifest itself and look into it.

I want something like what [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62600611/get-labels-of-remote-docker-image) is asking, but for GCR instead of dockerhub.

Answer (score 2):

> I want something like what [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62600611/get-labels-of-remote-docker-image) is asking, but for GCR instead of dockerhub.

You're in luck because [Container Registry implements a Docker protocol](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/reference/docker-api)! This means you're actually able to reuse [its accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62627500/357774) (with some small modifications):

```
$ REGISTRY="eu.gcr.io"
$ IMAGE="[YOUR-PROJECT-ID]/[YOUR-IMAGE]"
$ TAG="latest"
$ TOKEN="$(gcloud auth print-access-token)"
$ DIGEST="$(curl -s -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" "https://$REGISTRY/v2/$IMAGE/manifests/$TAG" | jq '.config.digest' -r)"
$ curl -sL -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" "https://$REGISTRY/v2/$IMAGE/blobs/$DIGEST" | jq '.config.Labels'
```

This should give you a JSON-formatted collection of labels for the image without pulling the whole thing and save lots of time and bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

As of the moment, only Artifact Registry has the [Label Repositories](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/repositories/label-repos) option to identify and group related repositories.

I would suggest if you want to use labels, you may want to [migrate from Google Container Registry to Artifact Registry](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/transition/transition-from-gcr) in order to use Label Repositories.

Another option is you may want to file this one as a [feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers). Please be advised that this doesn't have a specific ETA however you can still keep track of the progress by following the thread once the ticket has been created.